# CSS Counters not updating in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm using CSS counters to create a set of lists and subheadings. Here's the CSS

```
div.question {padding-left:2.5em; text-indent:-2.5em; counter-increment:item}
div.question:before {display:inline-block; width:2em; margin-right:0.5em; text-     align:right; content:counter(item, decimal)}
div.subheading {counter-increment:none; counter-reset:item}
div.subheading:before {display:inline-block;content:none}
```

A Div with the class "question" should be numbered, whereas a div with the class "subheading" should have no numbering and should reset the numbering back to zero, so the next question will be 1.

This works fine in all the browsers I've tested it on as long as the content is static. However, if I use javascript to change the class from question to subheading Chrome won't reset the counters. This works fine in Firefox (v19) and Internet Explorer 8

There's a JSFiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/NW43P/1/

As you can see the first subheading, which is loaded statically, correctly resets the counter. However, the second Heading, which is generated dynamically, fails to reset the counter.

I'm not sure if this is a bug in chrome or a problem with my code (I'm betting the latter), but does anyone know of a fix?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Looks like a Chrome/WebKit bug to me.

Comment: or a sandboxing issue.

Comment: Interesting, it works if you don't put your code inside `window.onload`. http://jsfiddle.net/NW43P/5/

Comment: TBH, in the actual code the class is changed using the CSS binding in knockout, which doesn't run onload. The fiddle was just a simplified example which I thought captured the problem. It's certainly interesting that your fiddle works and gives me something to experiment with. Thanks.

Comment: @toasties any luck with this? Ran into the same issue (inside contentEditable though).

Answer (score 1):

try reset the subsection counter in the section tag and increase the counter in the section:before. This works for me in the Chrome.

Example:

```
/* Header Numbering */

h1 {
    counter-reset: h2ctr; 
}

h1::before {
    counter-increment: h1ctr;
    content: counter(h1ctr) ". ";
}

h2 {
    counter-reset: h3ctr;
}

h2::before {
    counter-increment: h2ctr;
    content: counter(h1ctr) "." counter(h2ctr) " ";
}
```

Comment: I added a `counter-increment: tablecounter` to a element/CSS class of the container, and now it works, even with Angular and `:host ::ng-deep table {counter-increment}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can't edit the :before and :after pseudo elements? Or when you change the DOM after page is loaded.
For a fix, you could maybe consider using an ordered list? Instead of using the counter element? It would also be less code I guess?